# It is often easier to fight for principles than to live up to them.

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It is often easier to fight for principles than to live up to them. [Adlai Stevenson, speech, New York City, Aug. 27, 1952]

I read this sentence from [principle | Origin and meaning of principle by Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/principle)

I understand it literally and love it, but I cannot grasp its complete idea from my 27 years experience.

Comment: Seems like you are asking a philosophy question, not a language one. To confirm the literal part, "fighting for your principles" is the battle you fight to meet/follow them. "Living up to your principles" is practicing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fighting for your principles" means that you're trying to get them established in society and to get other people to agree that these principles are important.  "Living up to your principles" means embodying them in your own personal life, especially when it might involve some personal cost or sacrifice.

For example, consider the principle that "everyone deserves a living wage."  A politician might fight for that principle by advocating for minimum wage laws or for comprehensive public education and job training programs.  If it was discovered that this same politician had a nanny for his children to whom he was paying almost no salary, then this politician will have failed to *live up* to that same principle.